How can I include jar files for clojure in JNI inside a c++ binary created with bazel
Hello I am working on this project: https://github.com/svazqz/plClojure
But currently I am facing an issue after building the c++ binary, when I run the file create after the build step I get:
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000105d3894c, pid=12933, tid=259
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (21.0.2) (build 21.0.2)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (21.0.2, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-aarch64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x42894c]  jni_CallStaticObjectMethodV+0x9c
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/$USER/Projects/plClojure/hs_err_pid12933.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues
#
zsh: abort      ./bazel-bin/src/pl_clojure

Which in summary is related to:
Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.124 Thread 0x000000014880a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError'{0x0000000787f120c0}: clojure/java/api/Clojure> (0x0000000787f120c0) 
thrown [src/hotspot/share/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp, line 301]
Event: 0.124 Thread 0x000000014880a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x0000000787f123c8}: var> (0x0000000787f123c8) 
thrown [src/hotspot/share/prims/jni.cpp, line 1072]

I have tried different ways of adding clojure jar files as dependencies in the project but either the bazel sync fails when downloading the deps or the binary still throwing the previous exception after dependencies have been successfully downloaded and binary has been built.
How can I add the required jar files and then use them in the c++ code, using bazel?
I have tried using this rules:
http_archive(
    name = "rules_clojure",
    sha256 = "c841fbf94af331f0f8f02de788ca9981d7c73a10cec798d3be0dd4f79d1d627d",
    strip_prefix = "rules_clojure-c044cb8608a2c3180cbfee89e66bbeb604afb146",
    urls = ["https://github.com/simuons/rules_clojure/archive/c044cb8608a2c3180cbfee89e66bbeb604afb146.tar.gz"],
)

load("@rules_clojure//:repositories.bzl", "rules_clojure_dependencies", "rules_clojure_toolchains")

rules_clojure_dependencies()

rules_clojure_toolchains()

And I want to be able to use clojure inside c++ code like this:
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/Library/external/spec_alpha/spec.alpha-0.1.143.jar:/Library/external/clojure/clojure-1.9.0.jar";
In order to be able to run clojure code throw c++ interface.

Are you using bazel all the way ? How do you compile your cpp and how do you load libjvm.so ? If you could add the content of relevant cpp and BUILD.bazel file, it would help.

2 Things:

you jar option is based on a relative path and it could not be  resolving to the correct path.
You could manually add the jar and its classes to the class path and load the classes into the JVM. you can do this immediately after creating the Java vm in your main.cpp file by adding this function and calling it:


    void add_path(JNIEnv* env, const std::string& path)
    {
        const std::string urlPath = "file:/"+path;
        jclass classLoaderCls = env->FindClass("java/lang/ClassLoader");
        jmethodID getSystemClassLoaderMethod = env- >GetStaticMethodID(classLoaderCls, "getSystemClassLoader", "()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;");
        jobject classLoaderInstance = env- >CallStaticObjectMethod(classLoaderCls, getSystemClassLoaderMethod);
        jclass urlClassLoaderCls = env->FindClass("java/net/URLClassLoader");
        jmethodID addUrlMethod = env->GetMethodID(urlClassLoaderCls, "addURL", "(Ljava/net/URL;)V");
        jclass urlCls = env->FindClass("java/net/URL");
        jmethodID urlConstructor = env->GetMethodID(urlCls, "<init>", " (Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        jobject urlInstance = env->NewObject(urlCls, urlConstructor, env- >NewStringUTF(urlPath.c_str()));
        env->CallVoidMethod(classLoaderInstance, addUrlMethod, urlInstance);
        std::cout << "Added " << urlPath << " to the classpath." << std::endl;
    }


Your main.cpp file would look like this:
#include <jni.h>       /* where everything is defined */
#include <cstring>

void add_path(JNIEnv* env, const std::string& path)
{
    const std::string urlPath = "file:/"+path;
    jclass classLoaderCls = env->FindClass("java/lang/ClassLoader");
    jmethodID getSystemClassLoaderMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(classLoaderCls, "getSystemClassLoader", "()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;");
    jobject classLoaderInstance = env- >CallStaticObjectMethod(classLoaderCls, getSystemClassLoaderMethod);
    jclass urlClassLoaderCls = env->FindClass("java/net/URLClassLoader");
    jmethodID addUrlMethod = env->GetMethodID(urlClassLoaderCls, "addURL", "(Ljava/net/URL;)V");
    jclass urlCls = env->FindClass("java/net/URL");
    jmethodID urlConstructor = env->GetMethodID(urlCls, "<init>", " (Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    jobject urlInstance = env->NewObject(urlCls, urlConstructor, env- >NewStringUTF(urlPath.c_str()));
    env->CallVoidMethod(classLoaderInstance, addUrlMethod, urlInstance);
    std::cout << "Added " << urlPath << " to the classpath." << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
    JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/Library/external/spec_alpha/spec.alpha-0.1.143.jar:/Library/external/clojure/clojure-1.9.0.jar";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
    /* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
     * pointer in env */
    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    delete options;

    add_path(env, "path to jar")

    jclass Clojure = env->FindClass("clojure/java/api/Clojure");
    jmethodID var = env->GetStaticMethodID(Clojure, "var", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lclojure/lang/IFn;");
    jobject load_string = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(Clojure, var, env->NewStringUTF("clojure.core"), env->NewStringUTF("load-string"));
    jmethodID load_string_invoke = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(load_string), "invoke", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    env->CallObjectMethod(load_string, load_string_invoke, env->NewStringUTF("(prn (+ 1 2 3 4 5))"));

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}


